# changing the background image of decorated tab bar in gwt

Tags: java, css, gwt, tabbar

how do you change the background image of a decorated tabBar in gwt or the decorated tabBar wont accept a background image? here is the css I did

```
.gwt-DecoratedTabBar {
width: 910px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #565F68 url(images/topBar.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

and I want to put all my images in a folder called assets instead of the default images folder
how do I refer to that folder in the css

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
.gwt{
    position: absolute;
    width: 910px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('images/topBar.jpg') no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I´m not quite sure, that you can specify so many attributes in background.

Also, you just need to create a folder called assets, and change 'image/' to 'assets/'.